# One-dimensional family of complex algebraic K3 surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, k3-surfaces

Let $X$ be an algebraic complex K3 surface, we know that $X$ is deformation equivalent to a smooth quartic surface or more generally a K3 surface with Picard number $1$ (a very general K3 surface in the family of K3 surfaces). It means that there exists a proper morphism $\mathcal{X}\rightarrow S$ with each fibre a K3 surface, $\mathcal{X}_{\eta}=X$ ($\eta$ a general point on $S$) and $\rho(\mathcal{X}_t)=1$ for some closed $t\in S$.

> I want to show that $S$ can be a smooth algebraic curve or better be $\mathbb{A}^1$.

Comment: What is the relation between $X$ in your first and second sentences?

Comment: @Sasha They are the same algebraic complex K3 surface.

Comment: The first was complex, i.e., over $\mathbb{C}$, and the second is over the field of functions on $S$ (this would be the standard meaning of $\eta$), so they can't be the same. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: @Sasha You are corrected, here I mean the fibre over a general point.

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  By Gritsenko-Hulek-Sankaran, the moduli spaces of genus $g$ K3 surfaces are of general type for $g$ sufficiently positive.  So you cannot make the base be rational or elliptic.

Comment: Just a little addendum to Jason Starr's comment. Namely, the moduli stack $M_d$ of polarized K3 surfaces of *any* fixed degree $d$ is hyperbolic (i.e., every holomorphic map $\mathbb{C}\to  M_d^{an}$ is isoconstant). This implies that  $S$ can't be $\mathbb{A}^1$, unless $X$ is already Picard rank one (take the trivial family). The reason $M_d$ is hyperbolic is because polarized K3 surfaces satisfy the infinitesimal Torelli property, so that hyperbolicity follows from a theorem of Griffiths-Schmid in Hodge Theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose any ample class in $\mathrm{Pic}(X)$, assume its degree is $d$. Let $M_d$ be the moduli space of polarized K3 surfaces of degree $d$ with appropriate level structure so that it has a universal family (alternatively one can use here the $\mathrm{Quot}$-scheme that is used to construct the moduli space). Let $x \in M_d$ be the point that corresponds to $X$. Let $S_0 \subset M_d$ be a general curve in $M_d$ through $x$, and let $S \to S_0$ be a resolution of singularities of $S_0$. Then the pullback to $S$ of the universal family from $M_d$ is a family with the required properties.

Comment: What is a *general* curve means?

Comment: $M_d$ is a quasiprojective variety of dimension $19$. So, you can choose an embedding into a projective space, and intersect with $18$ general hyperplanes passing through $x$.